# How can I unclose my PSN account?

Tags: ps4, psn

My PS4 was hacked recently and money was being taken out of it. I called PSN support and they closed my account.

Now I can't get it unclosed. Help!

Comment: according to [this](https://community.playstation.com/content/pdc/us/en_US/pdc-communities/support/PlayStation-Network-Support.topic.html/how_do_i_take_money-PTCj.html) it's not possible to take money out of a PSN Wallet

Answer (score 2):

They only way to reactivate an account is to contact PSN support again and get them to help you secure the account from the hacker and 'unclose' it.

Deactivating the account is an instant way to stop the hacker from making more purchases while you sort it out with PSN and your bank.

Although this hasn't happened to me on PSN it has on other services where someone was using my card details to make purchases, you will probably just need to change your password.

If you are using that password for any other sites or services you need to change it there too, it has been compromised.

The hacker may have had access to some or all of your your card details via your PSN account too so I would tell your bank that fraudulent payments have been made with the card, they will probably replace it.